# Trying to get JavaFX 2.0 3D working on an intel 945

Tags: 3d, driver, javafx, intel, javafx-2

JavaFX 2.0 doesn't support 3D with my driver.

- JavaFX beta build 40
- OS: Windows Vista
- graphics: Mobile Intel 945 Express Chipset Family
- driver version: 7.14.10.1504 (current)
- latest driver according to intel: 15.8.3.1504 on dl page, the file installs version 7.14.10.1504 (http://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?lang=eng&changeLang=true&DwnldId=16312)

I found this: "The minimum driver version for Intel HD was recently changed to 8.15.10.2302 to workaround bugs in older drivers." (https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2255278)

Drivers with version >= 8.15.10.2302 are not availabe for the 945. Is there any workaround for this workaround, i.e. can I convince JavaFX to support 3D anyway? Any alternative drivers? Might using mesa help?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Windows 7 has the later updates for that graphics card. Have you tried installing a Windows 7 version and see if it works? There are applications that give your computer fake graphics card name so it can run games that wont run on non supported hardware. There is also probably graphics card hackers groups that create drivers for Intel using divers from later models (I know of ATI and Nividia ones).

I bet there also will be a flag for JavaFX to force support a graphics card. They have a flag for Java to do such a thing for Java2D. You might want to ask on the JavaFX official form.

Answer (score 0):

There is not way to support Intel 945 Chipsets in JavaFX 2.0 Hardware Accelerated. The Problem is it needs Pixel Shader 3.0 to utilize hardware acceleration, [but the Chipset only supports PS 2.0.](http://www.intel.com/support/graphics/sb/cs-014257.htm).

You can find more details on wy it not uses hardware acceleration with following commands:

set NWT_TRACE_LEVEL=4
java -Dprism.verbose=true